# How to send the drop down list value to an email?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an question that I need to send selected drop down list value to an email.I already sent the other input values in the contact form to an email. But I do not know how to send the drop down list value to an email. Herewith attached the html, php and js code. Could anyone can help me?

Here is the html code

```
<!-- Contact form -->

 <div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Form</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name" style="border: 1px solid #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputService">Service</label>
                        <select name="subject" class="form-control"
                        id="inputService" size="1">
                        <option value="Option1">Pr-Matrimonial Services</option>
                        <option value="Option2">Extra Marital Affairs</option>
                        <option value="Option3">Divorce Case Support</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code...

```
<script>
function submitContactForm(){
    var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
    if(name.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(name.trim() != '' && !usernameRegex.test(name)){
        alert('Please enter valid name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(message.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your message.');
        $('#inputMessage').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'contact.php',
            data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#inputName').val('');
                    $('#inputEmail').val('');
                    $('#inputMessage').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</p>');
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

php code...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['contactFrmSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) && !empty($_POST['message'])){


    // Submitted form data
    $name   = $_POST['name'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];
    $option= $_POST["subject"];

    /*
     * Send email to admin
     */
    $to     = 'support@ribelz.net';
    $subject= 'Contact Request of privateeyelk.com';

    $htmlContent = '
    <h4>Contact request from : '.$email.'</h4>

    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email: '.$email.'</p>
    <p>Message: '.$message.'</p>
    <p>Service: '. $option.'</p>
    ';

    // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: Private Eye<privateeyelk.com>' . "\r\n";

    // Send email
    if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
        $status = 'ok';
    }else{
        $status = 'err';
    }

    // Output status
    echo $status;die;

    }
```

Comment: But it does not get the value. It gets empty field in the email.

Comment: Looks like you didn't retrieve the value of select `inputService` in Javascript, try: `var subject = $('#inputService').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't retrieve the value of select in your Js code

Try adding this line in your  submitContactForm function

```
var subject = $('#inputService').val();
```

Please check this line to

```
data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message+'&service='+subject,
```

Comment: I added it now but it does not get the value. It gets empty field in the email.

Comment: did you check whether select value is exist in db or not?

Comment: I did not use a db.

Comment: $message= 'My select menu value is '. $option; try adding like this

Comment: The contact form gets error.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It does not give to submit the form.

Comment: data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message, check this line in data you didn't add that select option

Comment: It shows same error

Comment: did you added select option  value in before line?

Comment: No I didn't add

Comment: i have updated my answer please check once again